# Comparar dos fechas con carbon en laravel

Tags: laravel, carbon

quiero comparar dos fechas usando `Carbon`. Las dos fechas son las siguientes.

```
$fecha1 = '2023-10-20'
$fecha2 = '2023-10-20'
```

y el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
if (Carbon::parse($fecha1)->gt(Carbon::parse($fecha2 ))){

            return true;
        }
```

Este codigo funciona perfecto si las fechas no son iguales. Pero problema que estoy teniendo con este codigo es que cuando las fechas son iguales me lanza un error de validación y no deberia ser asi. Ademas quisiera saber que cantidad de noches existe entre las dos fechas

Alguna propuesta de solucion usando `Carbon`

Answer (score 1):

el detalle es que estas validando si es mas mayor, tambien debes pasarle el formato

ejemplo:

- eq() igual
- ne() no es igual
- gt() mayor que
- gte() mayor o igual que
- lt() menor que
- lte() menor o igual

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$fecha1 = Carbon::parse('2023-10-20')->format('Y-m-d');
$fecha2 = Carbon::parse('2023-10-20')->format('Y-m-d');

if( $fecha1->eq($fecha2)){
 // resto del codigo
}
```

para ver los dias de diferencia seria:

```
$dias = $fecha1->diffInDays($fecha2);
```

referencia y documentancion:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: Muchas Gracias, edite mi pregunta y adicione otra interrogante. Como saber la cantidad de noches que hay entre esas dos fechas